# Toggle display by array.push and pop

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm trying to make an analog for classlist toggle *without JQuery* that works lower than IE 10 with multiple elements to show (.show is display:block) , but my code doesn't work:

(When boxbutton is clicked, box and backdrop are shown, and you can close the box by clicking either boxclose or backdrop)

```
<script>
var classList = document.getElementsByClassName('openthis').className.split(" ");

function openbox() {
classList.push(" show");
};

function closebox() {
classList.pop ( );
};
</script>


<span onclick="openbox();" id="boxbutton">open the box</span>

<div class="openthis" id="box">
<div onclick="closebox();" class="boxclose">X</div>
</div>

<div onclick="closebox();" class="openthis" id="backdrop"></div>
```

Please, help!

Comment: Please could you be more clear? Please show us the html src before click and the expected html after click, because I see two times the same code.

Comment: What is more, "Need to be shown" open a `div` that never is closed.

Comment: @Fabricio it's the two elements being shown from one click, a box and a backdrop, and you can press either of them to close the box (like a confirmation window on some facebook)

Comment: @Fabricio updated for more clarity

Comment: Cool, let me try something....

Comment: please take a look at the answer.

Comment: I think this won't work, because ClassName is a string, so you'll end up with a simple array.

Answer (score 0):

The right way in your code is to use [claseList](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) instead of `className` because it allow you to add or remove class from a DOM node.

I've also remove the `var classList` becuase it is not needed, and I've initialized the hidden div with the class `hidden` (take a look at the CSS code).

The approach in `openbox` and `closebox` is to get the notes with class `openthis` and add or remove the `hidden` class depends of the case.

```js
function openbox() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('openthis');
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(el) {
    el.classList.remove("hidden");
  });
};

function closebox() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('openthis');
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(el) {
    el.classList.add("hidden");
  });
};
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<span onclick="openbox();" id="boxbutton">open the box</span>

<div class="openthis hidden" id="box">
  <div onclick="closebox();" class="boxclose">X</div>
</div>

<div onclick="closebox();" class="openthis hidden" id="backdrop">
  Backdrop
</div>
```

**Edit 1:**

This second version works for browsers that doesn't not support `classList` method. Is a litter more expensive but it works!

```js
function openbox() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('openthis');
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(el) {
    removeClass(el, "hidden");
  });
};

function closebox() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('openthis');
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(el) {
    addClass(el, "hidden");
  });
};

function addClass(element, classToAdd) {
  var className = element.className;
  element.className = className + " " + classToAdd;
}

function removeClass(element, classToRemove) {
  var className = element.className;
  element.className = className.replace(new RegExp("(?:^|\\s+)" + classToRemove + "(?:\\s+|$)", "g"), "");
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<span onclick="openbox();" id="boxbutton">open the box</span>

<div class="openthis hidden" id="box">
  <div onclick="closebox();" class="boxclose">X</div>
</div>

<div onclick="closebox();" class="openthis hidden" id="backdrop">
  Backdrop
</div>
```

I hope that helps :D

Comment: I'm really sorry, but classList is only IE10>, and that's the reason why I tried the arrays :S

Comment: @yve I've added the IE < 10 version